# Create Customization Controls from Array

Tags: php, loop, array, theme-customizer

Coming from a Javascript background and humbly jumping into WP dev I'm having some trouble with PHP (especially in a WordPress context).

**Here's what I'm trying to do:**
Create controls for the customizer from an array; specifically, social icon url inputs for a plethora of social sites.

**Here's what I've tried (and isn't working):**

```
$socialIcons = array (

  array( 'name' => 'behance', 'label' => 'Behance URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'bitbucket', 'label' => 'BitBucket URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'digg', 'label' => 'Digg URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'dribble', 'label' => 'Dribble URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'facebook', 'label' => 'Facebook URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'flickr', 'label' => 'Flickr URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'forest', 'label' => 'Forest URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'github', 'label' => 'GitHub URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'gplus', 'label' => 'Google Plus URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'instagram', 'label' => 'Instagram URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'lastfm', 'label' => 'Lastfm URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'linkedin', 'label' => 'LinkedIn URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'pintrest', 'label' => 'Pintrest URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'reddit', 'label' => 'Reddit URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'soundcloud', 'label' => 'SoundCloud URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'stackexchange', 'label' => 'StackExchange URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'stackoverflow', 'label' => 'StackOverflow URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'twitter', 'label' => 'Twitter URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'vimeo', 'label' => 'Vimeo URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'vk', 'label' => 'VK URL' ),
  array( 'name' => 'youtube', 'label' => 'YouTube URL' ),

);

$i = 0;
foreach ($socialIcons as $icon) {
  $i = $i++
  $wp_customize->add_setting(
    'pxk_href_' . $icon['name'], // use this in twig file call to theme_mod
    array(
      'default'         => '',
      'transport'       => 'postMessage',
      'priority'        => $i
    )
  );

  $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Control(
      $wp_customize,
    'custom_href_' . $icon['name'],
      array(
        'label'          => __( $icon['label'], 'pxk' ),
        'section'        => 'social',
        'settings'       => 'pxk_href_' . $icon['name'],
        'type'           => 'url',
        'input_attrs'    => array(
          'placeholder' => 'http://your ' . $icon['name']
        ),
      )
    )
  );
};
```

This throws a PHP syntax parsing error, stating `unexpected '$wp_customize' (T_VARIABLE)...`

I suspect I need to organize this into a function or two, return or echo the `$wp_` arrow functions, and perhaps call it differently in order to successfully create a setting and control for each item of the array. Ideas?

Any feedback/help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add ";" after  $i = $i++ and see if that fixes your issue

```
foreach ($socialIcons as $icon) {
  $i = $i++;
  $wp_customize->add_setting(
    'pxk_href_' . $icon['name'], // use this in twig file call to theme_mod
    array(
      'default'         => '',
      'transport'       => 'postMessage',
      'priority'        => $i
    )
  );
```

Comment: Ha! Can't believe I missed that one. If only PHP were more forgiving with semi-colons. That did the trick. Many thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped :)